# Belkin F7D1301 v1 wireless router connection resets ever 30 mins

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a Belkin F7D1301 v1 wireless router which is connected to a DSL modem.
The connection works fine for 30 mins, after that it just stops working. The solution is to restart the modem and the router.

Also as the wifi connection is shared among mobiles, an iPad and a few laptops.So any device which connects to the wifi also sometimes takes down the connection.

Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the router.

Belkin routers are known to have horribly bad firmware, and it looks very much like this particular model can't be modified to run DD-WRT or similar.

This kind of problem is typical.  (FWIW I purchased a number of the "newer version" of this router, so I did  quite a bit of research on.  Unfortunately It looks to me like Belkin has not upgraded the firmware since 2010)

Comment: Any suggestions for a replacement router?

Comment: This forum is not for asking sales advice but I'd suggest getting a router which supports DD-WRT - that way you know you can load an after-market, feature rich, stable firmware on it regardless of manufacturer.  Definitely get an 802.11n router.  The rest of the answer depends on budget - if you need lots of speed look for multiple antennas (and then dual radios if you have gear which works in 5g band).  GigE ports are a "nice-to-have", but won't generally make much difference for WIFI connections as you almost never get advertised speed.  A cheap router can still give you a decent connection.